# Get contents from file into bash variables

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get contents from a text file into seperate bash variables but I can't get my head around it.

In total 3 variables need to be fetched from the 2nd line.

```
;File created: 20200727
user.details 184 16 John Smith
```

Output needs to be:

```
USERID="184"
GROUPID="16"
FULLNAME="John Smith"
```

Any ideas? I've tried to seperate it via grep, but as values change thats not an option. Same to awk. Problem I am struggling with is that the last variable can be of any length including spaces, which I previously used as delimiter. The source file can't be changed unfortunately.

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: `Any ideas?` Many! What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried to seperate it via grep, but as values change thats not an option. Same to awk. Problem I am struggling with is that the last variable can be of any length including spaces, which I previously used as delimiter. The source file can't be changed unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe this: `read -r _ USERID GROUPID FULLNAME < <(grep -Fm1 user.details file)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this with `awk`:

```
awk '/user\.details/ {
print "USERID=\""$2"\""
print "GROUPID=\""$3"\""
print "FULLNAME=\""substr($0, index($0,$4))"\""}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
while read -r foo USERID GROUPID FULLNAME; do [[ $foo != ";File" ]] && echo "$USERID $GROUPID $FULLNAME"; done < file
```

Output:

```
184 16 John Smith
```

Variable `$FULLNAME` contains everything from the third column onwards.